# Android Audio Manager/Service Error: receiver and context package names don't match

Tags: android

I have this error:

```
E/AudioManager(2221): registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()   
           error: receiver and context package names don't match
```

Can anyone elaborate what possibly I'm doing wrong? I tried to put all my Classes under one package but to no avail!

Comment: this error/warning came from a mag stripe sdk I use (from IDTECH) so I have no control over the source code. Despite the error/warning above, my implementation is running ok. Guess I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: @Louie did you resolve it?

Comment: Nope, the source is from IDTECH api in which I have no control. It seems that the error is caught from within the api so it continues the execution and my application still run smooth

Comment: Another thing, I realized that the error is not in my code so I ignored it.